# Copy folders has specific part of name and it is content

Tags: shell, command-line, directory, cp, file-copy

I have a long list of folder as follow:

```
001_bat_3513
002_mon_3213
003_bat_3515
004_btt_3540
005_bat_4513
055_bpt_8523
056_bot_3513
058_bat_1513
.
.
```

From this list: 
How can I copy the folders ( and all its content) that has the part " bat" in its name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use shell globbing for this:

```
cp -rp *bat*/ /destination/
```

Here `*bat*/` will expand to directories having `bat` in their names.

Or using `find`, which will work even if there are so many files that you get an error because the command line is too long:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '*bat*' -exec cp -rpt /destination {} +
```

Comment: Thank you very much . Kindly one more question. how can i rename all the folders by removing the first three numbers from it is name?

Comment: @goro Thats easy. Could you please ask it as a new question with your expected file names?

Comment: New question or just edit this one?

Comment: @goro No, this one is already answered. You should mark it as accepted and ask any new query as a new one..check the site FAQ.

Comment: @don_crissti Yeah..edited..

Comment: Why so complicated? You don't need `find`, `cp -t`, zsh features, or loops for this.

Comment: @Gilles duh..I don't know what I was thinking.. edited..